# upload picture when register forum

Tags: php

is it something wrong with my code? 
i did all right, but still cant upload picture
the eror no show anything, that's why i so confuse what the problem is
please help me

this my form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="save_register.php">
```

and this is my php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
        $password1=$_POST['password1'];
        $password2=$_POST['password2'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $bday = $_POST['day'];
        $bmonth = $_POST['month'];
        $byear = $_POST['year'];
        $countrys = $_POST['country'];
        $avatar=$_POST['avatar'];
        if($email=='' || $first_name=='' || $password1=='' || $password2=='' || $gender=='' || $bday=='' || $bmonth=='' || $byear=='' || $countrys=='')
        {echo '<h2>Maaf, data Anda tidak lengkap</h2>';}else
        {if($password1!=$password2){
            echo '<h2>Password Anda tidak sama!</h2>';}
        else
    //cek data sudah tersedia
    {
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) as cek FROM `user_login` WHERE email = '".$admin."'";
        //echo $sql;
        $ambil_data = mysql_query($sql);
        if($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
        {
            $cek = 0;
            $cek = $data["cek"];
        }
        //jika data sudah ada
        if ($cek==1)
        echo "Data already exist";
        else //Proses simpan
            {
                //upload image
                $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
                $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $extension = end($temp);
                if((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
                || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "")
                &&($_FILES["file"]["size"] >=0) || ($_FILES["file"]["size"]<200000)
                && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
                {
                    //cek file upload
                    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"]==0)
                    {
                        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br>";
                        echo "Upload: ". $_FILES["file"]["name"]. "<br>";
                        echo "Type: ". $_FILES["file"]["name"]. "<br>";
                        echo "Size: ". ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024). "kB<br>";
                        echo "Temp file: ". $_FILES["file"]["name"]. "<br>";
                        if(file_exists("image/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                        {
                            echo"<tr><td>".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."Please Rename Your File.</td></tr>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (email, first_name, last_name, password, gender, b_day, b_month, b_year, country, image) VALUES 
                                        ('$email', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$password1', '$gender', '$bday', '$bmonth', '$byear', '$countrys','$avatar')";
                            //echo $sql;
                            $result=@mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
                            if($result)
                            {
                            echo '<h2>Registration Success</h2><br><a href="login.php">Continue Login</a>';
                            }else
                            {
                            echo '<h2>Error, tidak bisa menyimpan data ke database</h2>';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    }   
}     }

?>
```

sorry,this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Registration</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
<body  background="image/background.jpg">
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <table border="1" width="80%" height="500" align="center" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" ><form id="form1" name="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="save_register.php">

        <tr>
            <td widht="20" align="center" valign="top" id="loginform"><strong><font size="10"> Register Form</font></strong>
                <table border="1" width="60%" height="150"  align="center"   >

                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="3"><strong>Account Information</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td  align="center" colspan="3" ><table border="1" bgcolor="white" width="100" height="100" ><tr><td align="center"><input name="avatar" type="hidden" value="avatar/profil.jpg" /><img src="avatar/profil.jpg" ></tr></td></table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><Input type="file" name="file"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="50%">Email</td><td>:</td><td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Password</td><td>:</td><td><input name="password1" type="password" id="password1" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Retype Password</td><td>:</td><td><input name="password2" type="password" id="password2" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="3"><strong>Personal Information</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">First Name</td><td>:</td><td><input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Last Name</td><td>:</td><td><input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Gender</td><td>:</td><td><font color="green"><input type="radio" name="gender" checked value="Male"> Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female </font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Birthday</td><td>:</td>
                        <td width="65%" >
                        <select name="day">
                        <option value="-">-</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Country</td><td>:</td>
                        <td width="65%" >
                        <select name="country">
                    <option value="">Country</option>
                    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>

                </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </td>
            <td  rowspan="2" widht="30%" align="center"><img src="image/dotareg.png" width="400" height="450" ></td>
        </tr>




    </form>
    </table>
</font>
</body>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: the html input for the file is?

Comment: if you are in local/server, maybe the image exceeds the max size file to upload and will not show any error, and of course, will not upload it

Comment: show your HTML you posted a little bit

Comment: where is the code to upload the file? I don't see anywhere in your code where you upload the file to your server?!

Comment: i edit already sir ,sorry

Comment: No need to say sorry, but where is your code where you upload the image to YOUR server?

Comment: yea,thx, i edited already, the php and the html, are there any missing